# Load a custom style before the whole page is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I need to load different CSS files in contains different colors like a style switcher. and I want to load the color.css before DOM is loaded. I tried the window.onload but always I see default.css is loaded before.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Style switcher</title>
    <!-- ===== Bootstrap CSS ===== -->
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
                $('#theme').attr({
                    href: 'css/colors/red.css'
                });
            }
            // document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
            //     $('#theme').attr({
            //         href: 'css/colors/red.css'
            //     });
            // });
    </script>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- ===== Custom CSS ===== -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- ===== Color CSS ===== -->
    <link href="css/colors/default.css" id="theme" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- ===== Main-Wrapper ===== -->
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- ===== Top-Navigation ===== -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top m-b-0">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <div class="top-left-part">
                    <a class="logo" href="index.html">
                        <b>
                          Test
                        </b>

                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
   </div>
   
</body>
```

Comment: `window.onload` means on window loaded

Comment: seealso https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload#Notes

Comment: @appleapple External style sheets don’t affect DOM, so DOMContentLoaded does not wait for them. I found this here https://javascript.info/onload-ondomcontentloaded .

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are trying to use jQuery before it is available, so that won't work.

Instead of changing the src of the link, you could just create a link tag dynamically with the correct source. I make use of an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to make the function execute directly ones it's loaded

Here is a small snippet that creates a link tag with the correct CSS source, you can change the source the whatever you need.

```
<script>
  (function () {
    const style = document.createElement("link"); // Create link element
    style.rel = "stylesheet"; // Set relationship to be a stylesheet
    style.href = "css/colors/red.css"; // Set the path to the CSS file

    document.head.appendChild(style); // Add link tag to the head element
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: thanks man. This is exactly what I need. I appreciate your help.